# How to store or upload audio file in specific location?

Tags: javascript, php

I need to store recorded voices at one specific location. How to store or upload recorded file to location?

Here is my script for upload audio file & upload.php file

This is my reference link: https://blog.addpipe.com/using-recorder-js-to-capture-wav-audio-in-your-html5-web-site/

```
//upload link
var upload = document.createElement('a');
upload.href="#";
upload.innerHTML = "Upload";
upload.addEventListener("click", function(event){
      var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onload=function(e) {
          if(this.readyState === 4) {
              console.log("Server returned: ",e.target.responseText);
          }
      };
      var fd=new FormData();
      fd.append("audio_data",blob, filename);
      xhr.open("POST","upload.php",true);
      xhr.send(fd);
})
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode (" "))//add a space in between
li.appendChild(upload)//add the upload link to li
```

upload.php

```
<?php
print_r($_FILES); //this will print out the received name, temp name, type, size, etc.
$size = $_FILES['audio_data']['size'];
$input = $_FILES['audio_data']['tmp_name'];
$output = $_FILES['audio_data']['name'].".wav";
move_uploaded_file($input, $output)
?>
```

Comment: It helps if you explain the issue you're facing. What happens when you run your code? Errors? Stored in wrong location? Wrong name? Computer crashes? Have you looked in the manual on how to use [move_uploaded_file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)?

Comment: I need to upload data at the specific location but it can't be store any location.

Comment: The second argument to move_uploaded_file() should include the path to where you want to store it, not just the filename. Something like: `move_uploaded_file($input, '/path/to/where/to/store/the/file/' . $output)`. You also need to make sure that folder is writeable for the user that runs the web server (usually www-data on *nix-systems)

Comment: it's not working

Comment: Check your web servers error log. The statement "it's not working" isn't enough for us to go on.

Comment: i have already checked, it's not showing any error log.

Answer (score 0):

target_dir=>where don you want to store it

```
  $target_dir = "uploads/";
   $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["audio_data"]["name"]);


 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["audio_data"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["audio_data"]["name"]). " has been 

   uploaded.";

  } else {
   echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
 }
```